# Cakephp background color for multiple input

Tags: css, forms, cakephp, input, background

I have an input form in my Cakephp 2.x application as below:

```
echo $this->Form->input('color_id', array('label' => 'Color', 'options' => $colors, 'empty' => false, 'multiple' => true));
```

I want to add css to the input where the background of the select is differ based on the option.

if color is red, the background color is red.

I already try this way:

```
echo $this->Form->input('color_id', array('label' => 'Color', 'options' => $colors, 'empty' => false, 'multiple' => true, 'style' => 'background:yellow;'));
```

but its for the whole input[type=select], not for each option.
can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the default form builder. You can use plain php to break the select like this:

```
$html = '<select name="position">';

$opts = array('red', 'green', 'blue');
foreach($opts as $option)
{
    $html .= '<option value="' . $option . '"';
    $html .= 'style=background-color:'.$option;
    $html .= '>' . ucfirst($option) . '</option>';
}
$html .= '</select>';

print $html;
```

If your colors are not exact css colors you can assign class with that name and then apply the colors via css.

Ex:

```
   $html .= 'class="'.$option.'"';
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I understand the idea there.
But in cakephp, the $opts is like:
'$colors = $this->Product->Color->find('list');' and i didnt know where to put the style.